# dlopen() ignoring $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-linking, dlopen, dynamic-loading

Trying to dynamically load `libOpenCL.so` in a program from my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is set to `./`. I double checked that `libOpenCL.so` is present in my current directory with the correct spelling, and I'm running the program below in my current directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


int main(void)
{
    const char* dl_path = "libOpenCL.so";

    if (dlopen(dl_path, RTLD_NOW) == NULL)
        printf("Cannot open shared lib: %s\n", dlerror());
    else
        printf("Open successful\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs: `Cannot open shared lib: libOpenCL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

It opens up fine when I call `dlopen()` with the relative path string i.e. `"./libOpenCL.so"`.

According to my understanding of `dlopen()`'s documentation, a non-empty `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be considered in the `.so` search with a few exceptions that shouldn't apply to my example. Anything else I might be doing wrong here?

This is for Arch Linux, glibc 2.29, GCC 9.1

Running it with:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
gcc -o test example.c && ./test
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. How are you running it?

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm doing `gcc -o test dltest.c -ldl && ./test`. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: You're not setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` anywhere in anything you've posted

Comment: I did mention early in the question that it was set to `./`

Comment: So I just ran it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./test` which was probably your point. It's working now.

Comment: How do you know that it was set to `./`?

Comment: @melpomene That's what echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH printed before I ran ./test

Comment: There are several ways to incorrectly set environment variables, so it's better to include the variable as part of the steps to reproduce just to remove (or confirm) any doubts about that.

Comment: Sounds like the variable wasn't `export`ed then, so it was just local to the shell and not exported to child processes

Comment: @thatotherguy Edited the question, you could answer it now

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize linking the suggested duplicate would immediately close the question.

Comment: Is it appropriate to reopen the question, @melpomene?

Comment: @JohnBollinger My gut feeling is no, but I'm open to other opinions.

Comment: Using the name `test` for a test program in Unix environments is seldom a good idea because the shells have a built-in `test` command and it is all too easy to run that instead of your test program (by accident, but to the confusion of everyone).  Simply don't create programs called `test`.  However, this is 100% tangential to your problem with `dlopen()` — it's just an observation based on 30+ years work on Unix machines.